# Refactoring code to have multiple web projects or sites in one solution

Tags: c#, .net

**Context:** I have a codebase that consists of an MVC project, WebAPI project and one web project in the same solution that was originally intended to consist of different websites for each of the functions / areas it has, for example within the solution there is a folder for the admin site eg views, service layer, repository etc, and for the customer site there is the same folder structure and files. The code in these two folders do not share the same service layer code and it is duplicated. I want to refactor the code for these two sites into a standard design and layers.

**Question:** What is the best approach for making these two areas appear as two separate sites in IIS? Currently there is only one site in IIS so it's not possible to have one running without the other. Would I need to make two separate web projects for these, refactor the code and then set the startup projects to multiple startup projects? Because knowing this will directly influence the refactoring of the two areas to use the same service layer logic and shared code.

Any pointers or suggestions on the design for this will be very much appreciated as I have not attempted this before having worked with only one web project within a solution and I would like advice from others who have worked with this type of design and refactoring to make multiple site nodes in IIS for areas/web projects in the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having 2 or more web projects in a solution and building and deploying separately to IIS. You might have an issue debugging both applications at the same time in the same instance of Visual Studio, but that's easily resolved by opening another Visual Studio!

And [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-Enterprise/dp/0735685355/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1509365674&sr=8-3&keywords=.net%20architecture) is a great book for looking at different solution layouts.

I've seen some good examples on github in the past too: https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD